# How to create multiple collapse functionalities in django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-templates

I have created a django template which show lists of subjects and i want to create collapse functionlities for each subject such that on click of it , it shows the available books.
For now i have used django template functionalities

```
{% for subject in subjects%}
 <span data-subject="{{subject.id}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#books_list">
    {{subject.name}}
 </span>
<div id="books_list">
{% for book in subject.books_set.all %}
<span>{{book.name}}</span>
{% endfor %}
</div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Now when i click on any of the subject it opens up the list of books of first subject.
How do i make sure that on click of particular subject it opens only its own books.

Comment: I think it's something about id. It should be unique for each list of books. Try to add forloop.counter in id to differ lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving multiple elements the same id which is never a good idea, you can append the id of the subject to the target/id of the elements to give them unique id's

```
{% for subject in subjects %}
    <span data-subject="{{subject.id}}"
          data-toggle="collapse" 
          data-target="#books_list{{ subject.id }}">
       {{subject.name}}
    </span>
    <div id="books_list{{ subject.id }}">
        {% for book in subject.books_set.all %}
            <span>{{book.name}}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great. Thnx. So it was all about the id.

Comment: @AmanGupta - Yes, id's should always be unique, if you find yourself needing a non-unique identifier, you should use a `class`, but yes, in this case, it should be unique